How do I set up a custom exit in electron-vite?
My app is frameless and I want to set up a custom logout, but I end up getting app reload errors. How can I get an instance of the application to set up custom logout?
If anyone has encountered this task, please advise.
App.vue
<script setup lang="ts">

import { app } from 'electron'

const exitApplication = () => {
  app.quit(); //error
 }
</script>

<v-btn @click='exitApplication' block>Exit</v-btn>

I was looking towards ipcMain, but I never realized how to access the instance from any component of the application.
I tried to assign an id for the exit button, but it doesn't work.
const setButton = document.getElementById('btn')

setButton!.addEventListener('click', () => {
  //code
})

